# o-ring vs x-ring motorcycle drive chain for longevity

Tags: motorcycle

I was wondering which type of drive chain will have a longer life on a motorcycle, friction, cost and weight apart.
The weight is pretty similar between the two. The reduced friction of the x type vs o type is indifferent and only the cost is a noticeable difference. Apart from all these i was wondering, given the same proper cleaning/maintenance, which of the two types would live longer under touring utilization, scarcely in rainy days. I understand x-rings tend to seal better but o-rings are told to have a longer lifespan (as more "solid" rubber) before failing and letting dirt penetration.

EDIT: I have searched thoroughly most of the info and i have a very clear sense of x vs o rings chains but i found NO info explaining or even better actually comparing the longevity between these.

Comment: What is the application?

Comment: for context https://www.cycleworld.com/sport-rider/o-ring-vsx-ring-and-patching-tires-ask-geek/